# Now() do MySQL não exibe a hora correta

Tags: php, mysql

Preciso de alguma forma inserir no servidor a hora **EXATA** de quem envia uma mensagem para o banco de dados.

[image: ENVIADA AS 08:15 E 08:17]

Estou usando a função `NOW()` para registrar o momento:

```
"INSERT INTO `chat` (id_de, id_para, data, mensagem, hora) VALUES('$id_de','$id_para',NOW(),'$mensagem', DATE_FORMAT(now(), '%H:%i:%s'))"
```

Porem, mesmo assim não registra a hora corretamente..

> Teste as **08:17** // 14-07-2015 - PC   -->> **11:17:25**

Comment: Como você está gerando a data na variável $mensagem? Usando alguma função do PHP?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Isto é um problema de Time Zone:

A variável time_zone pode ser ajustada direto no console do cliente MySQL.

```
SET @@global.time_zone = '+3:00';
QUIT
```

Você precisa sair e entrar de novo na sua sessão MySQL para poder ver os efeitos.
Assim que reiniciar a sessão do MySQL, verifique novamente a hora atual:

```
SELECT NOW();
```

Se você tiver o banco de dados de nomes de zonas de fusos horários adequadamente configurado, pode se referir às zonas pelos seus nomes:

```
SET time_zone='America/Sao_Paulo';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: Brigadão Ricardo.